# How to prevent duplicates in MongoDB even if its coming from other field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema contains two types of mobile numbers, stored as:

```
{
      phoneCode: String,
      phoneNumber: String,

      mobileCode: String,
      mobileNumber: String
}
```

How can I handle duplicity while storing or updating data if:

1. there's a `phoneCode + phoneNumber` or `mobileCode + mobileNumber` combination already stored in either of **phone** or **mobile** fields.

For example, lets say my database has two documents:

```
[
  { phoneCode: "+1", phoneNumber: "5556667898", mobileCode: "+1", mobileNumber: "5556668899" },
  { phoneCode: "+1", phoneNumber: "6655777898", mobileCode: "+1", mobileNumber: "6665557788"},
]
```

And I try to update first document with: `mobileCode: +1`, `mobileNumber: 6665557788`.

It should be prevented as this combination already exist in second document's *mobile code and number* field.

I can write query to check before store or update like:

```
const { phoneCode, phoneNumber, mobileCode, mobileNumber } = req.body;

collection.findOne({
  $or:[
    { $and: [{ phoneCode },  { phoneNumber} ] },
    { $and: [{ mobileCode }, { mobileNumber }] },
    { $and: [{ phoneCode : mobileCode }, { phoneNumber : mobileNumber}] },
    { $and: [{ mobileCode: phoneCode },  { mobileNumber: phoneNumber }] }
  ]
})
```

But this does not feel optimize way, I want to handle it, so even if I have to add a third number I can handle that as well.

Comment: I think this is the way you can match all criteria as per your current schema.

Comment: This collection is in starting phase so I can change the way data is being stored, if there a better way to store two numbers in two parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the [Attribute Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern), you can move this subset of information into an array and reduce the indexing needs also. You turn this information into an array of key-value pairs:

```
{
  contacts: [{ code: String, number: String, type: String }]
}
```

For example, lets say your database has two documents:

```
[
  {
    contacts: [
      { code: "+1", number: "5556667898", type: "phone" },
      { code: "+1", number: "5556668899", type: "mobile" }
    ]
  },
  {
    contacts: [
      { code: "+1", number: "6655777898", type: "phone" },
      { code: "+1", number: "6665557788", type: "mobile" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Your query for single pair matching would be:

```
collection.findOne({
  "contacts.code": "+1",
  "contacts.number": "6665557788"
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hXbDN2oojIp)

Your query for multiple pair matching would be:

```
const { phoneCode, phoneNumber, mobileCode, mobileNumber } = req.body;

collection.findOne({
  "contacts.code": { $in: [phoneCode, mobileCode] },
  "contacts.number": { $in: [phoneNumber, mobileNumber] }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJc5pkq3o8N)

---

For more optimisation you can use indexes in contacts fields,

You can use [compound multi key index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#compound-multikey-indexes),

For a compound multikey index, each indexed document can have at most one indexed field whose value is an array,

```
collection.createIndex({ "contacts.code": 1, "contacts.number": 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to prevent duplicates **during insert**, perhaps a different DB design would be better e.g...

```
yourDb.phoneNumbers
yourDb.contacts

phoneNumbers: {
  "_id": "phonenumber in string without spaces, dashes, brackets e.g. +123456789",
  "contact": <contact ID>,
}

contacts: {
  "_id": UUID,
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "e.g. mobile",
      "number": "same as in phoneNumbers collection",
      "display number": "number with formatting",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}

// Usage:
1. Create random UUID
2. Create phoneNumber document and try to insert into phoneNumbers (use above ID for contact)
3. If successful, create contact document and insert into contacts (user above ID for _id)
```

This design enables fast inserts (only requires checking PKs) and, as a bonus, you can use the phoneNumbers collection to quickly find contacts by phone number.

---

If your goal is to **find duplicates in DB, but not prevent them**, you can use your current structure and use the aggregation framework to find duplicates by projecting all types of phone numbers into a single phoneNumber string field + contactId field, then group by phoneNumber, collect contactId into array per phoneNumber, plus count of contactIds (countIds), filter where countIds > 1, then you have a list of phoneNumbers that are duplicates, together with contactIds that are sharing them.